# A collision probability.

Tags: probability

If I pick $\lfloor n^\alpha\rfloor$ integers from $0$ to $\lceil n^\beta\rceil$ uniformly where $0<\alpha\leq\frac12\leq\beta<1$ holds what is the probability that there are at least two integers within $2^{(\log\log n)^\gamma}$ apart for some fixed $\gamma\geq1$?

The probability there are two equal integers is given by birthday paradox.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Servaes what do you mean by 'there are two equal integers is the probability that there is at least one integer'? corrected ceil and floor (please dont modify your comments it is annoying).

Comment: @Servaes seems similar to birthday paradox but not sure.

Comment: Try to compute one minus the probabillity that none are within distance $D$ of each other. This should be roughly (I saw roughly as this does not take overlap into account) $1\cdot \frac{M-2D}{M}\cdot \frac{M-4D}{M}\cdot \frac{M-6D}{M}\cdots \cdot \frac{M-2(N-1)D}{M}$ (here drawing $N$ numbers from $[0,M]$). If $M \gg 2DN$ then this might be a decent approximation.

Comment: @Winther can you give exact asymptotics?